# PHP: how to merge one associative array into a sub-array of another multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a flat resultset, that looks like this in JSON:

```
[{
    "LineItemNo": "1",
    "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-1379",
    "St": "O",
    "PartNo": "F13DBX\/SPX35\/4P",
    "UnitPrice": "1.890"
}, {
    "LineItemNo": "1",
    "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-1379",
    "St": "O",
    "PartNo": "CF13DD\/E\/835",
    "UnitPrice": "1.920"
}, {
    "LineItemNo": "1",
    "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-1379",
    "St": "O",
    "PartNo": "QT13\/35-4",
    "UnitPrice": "1.770"
}, {
    "LineItemNo": "2",
    "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-4309",
    "St": "O",
    "PartNo": "F13DBX\/SPX35\/4P",
    "UnitPrice": "1.890"
}, {
    "LineItemNo": "2",
    "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-4309",
    "St": "O",
    "PartNo": "CF13DD\/E\/835",
    "UnitPrice": "1.920"
}, {
    "LineItemNo": "2",
    "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-4309",
    "St": "O",
    "PartNo": "QT13\/35-4",
    "UnitPrice": "1.770"
}]
```

I want to change it into this:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "LineItemNo": "1",
        "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-1379",
        "St": "O",
        "Parts": [{
            "PartNo": "F13DBX\/SPX35\/4P",
            "UnitPrice": "1.890"
        }, {
            "PartNo": "CF13DD\/E\/835",
            "UnitPrice": "1.920"
        }, {
            "PartNo": "QT13\/35-4",
            "UnitPrice": "1.770"
        }]
    }, {
        "LineItemNo": "2",
        "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-4309",
        "St": "O",
        "Parts": [{
            "PartNo": "F13DBX\/SPX35\/4P",
            "UnitPrice": "1.890"
        }, {
            "PartNo": "CF13DD\/E\/835",
            "UnitPrice": "1.920"
        }, {
            "PartNo": "QT13\/35-4",
            "UnitPrice": "1.770"
        }]
    }]
}
```

I've tried numerous things, but I haven't been able to find a way to iterate through the source array, create a `Parts` array during the process, and then plug values into that array during subsequent iterations.  What I'd like to do is iterate the source array, check the `$row['LineItemNo']` value, and if it has changed since the last iteration, create a new top-level array object.  If it hasn't, then create a new element the `Parts` array.

My basic code looks like this (I realize mysql is deprecated in favor of mysqli or PDO, but I'm stuck with it for the time being):

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$rs = array();
$rsParts = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if (!isset($ln) || $row['LineItemNo'] != $ln)
    {
        $ln = $row['LineItemNo'];
        $rs[data][] = array('LineItemNo' => $row['LineItemNo'], 'SolNo' => $row['SolNo'], 'St' => $row['St']);
        $rs[data][parts] = array();
    }
    array_push($rs[data][parts], array('PartNo' => $row['PartNo'], 'UnitPrice' => $row['UnitPrice']));
}
```

This is a good start, but it only gives me the parts in the first element, like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "0": {
            "LineItemNo": "1",
            "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-1379",
            "St": "O"
        },
        "parts": [{
            "PartNo": "F13DBX\/SPX35\/4P",
            "UnitPrice": "1.890"
        }, {
            "PartNo": "CF13DD\/E\/835",
            "UnitPrice": "1.920"
        }, {
            "PartNo": "QT13\/35-4",
            "UnitPrice": "1.770"
        }],
        "1": {
            "LineItemNo": "2",
            "SolNo": "SPE8E7-15-T-4309",
            "St": "O"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking that you can't re-initialize the array this way.  I've tried unsetting it when the LineItemNo changes, but that turns all the `Parts` elements into top-level elements.  I've tried only initializing the array at the beginning using `is_array`, but that puts all of the parts into the first top-level element (there are six parts in the first one and none in the second).

So, what's the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: the solution of the problem was to first send the resultset (`$result`) through this code:

```
$array = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $array[] = $r;
}
```

And then use SML's solution from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming any given `LineItemNo` would always be paired with the same `SolNo` and `St`, you can pass `LineItemNo` of each row to a function to check if the value exists in the sub-arrays of the result array `$rs`.

If `LineItemNo` doesn't already exist in `$rs`, then a new first level sub array of `$rs` is created and a 2nd level sub array containing `parts info` will also be added as sub_array of 1st level array element `parts`.

If `LineItemNo` does exist, then just add the `parts info` as sub_array of 1st level array element `parts`.

Since the top level array ['data'] you wanted in the output, doesn't do anything at this stage.
I strip that from the process and instead `$rs` is added to `$output['data']` in the final stage to form the output you need.

```
$rs=array();
$counter=0;
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $array[]=$r;
}

foreach ($array as $row) { 
  $part_info = array('part_no' => $row['PartNo'], 'unit_price' => $row['UnitPrice']);
  $temp=searchSub ($rs, $row['LineItemNo']);

    if ($temp===false){
       $rs[$counter] = array('LineItemNo' => $row['LineItemNo'], 'SolNo' => $row['SolNo'], 'St' => $row['St']);
       $rs[$counter]['parts'][] = $part_info;
       $counter++;
    }
    else {
        $rs[$temp]['parts'][]= $part_info;
    }
}
//function for subarray search
function searchSub($arr, $keyword){
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    {
        if (in_array($keyword, $value, true)!=false){
        return $key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$output['data']=$rs;
print_r($output);
```

[Test Result](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fbf929d683ad9bba8af328be99ee0b7a4b5d4cb1)

Comment: Why the counter? $key will do the exact same thing. It's redundant. Also why the search function?

Comment: @MikeBarwick the OP wants to move `parts_info` that shares the same `lineitemno`, `solno` and `st` to as sub arrays to the array `parts`, not just move `part_info` to a sub array. I hope I didn't misinterpret the questoin

Comment: @MikeBarwick $key would result in 5 sub-arrays, at the level after 'data', the output the OP wants should only have 2 sub-arrays at the level after 'data'

Comment: No. There's a good chance I have lol I give up. Hopefully this solves OPs. :)

Comment: No, SML, you interpreted the question correctly.  Thanks for taking a crack at this.  I find when I run this code, all the values are '1' for the first element (including all the values for parts), 'S', for the second one, 'O' for the third, and 'F' for the fourth.  Not sure where that's coming from, but I had something similar when messing with foreach.  Also, there are four parts for the first, and two for the next three.  There should be two top-level elements (removing data until the end is a good idea), with three parts each.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I hope it wasn't me who misinterpreted the Q and I am eager to learn if there is a more efficient way to group them than the use of a search function

Comment: @BobRodes I am having a hard time visualising what are trying to say, can you do a screenshot of the result and mark it?

Comment: SML you have the right idea. Bob, I hear you man lol. Multi-dimensional arrays are a lengthy annoying process lol

Comment: @BobRodes I tested with your json and got the exact result of your second json so not sure what is wrong without further info

Comment: @BobRodes http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fbf929d683ad9bba8af328be99ee0b7a4b5d4cb1  obviously since I have no SQL to fetch the data from, I used your $json as source and loop it in a foreach, have a look and let me know what you think

Comment: Something funny going on with the resultset.  I'll figure it out.  Presumably if you tested it with my two samples there's something wrong somewhere else.  Thanks very much for the bit of code!  I shall study it.

Comment: @BobRodes in the sample data you provided, the top level is Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LineItemNo] => 1, if your real data has additional level, you would need to enclose my code in additional foreach to get to the right level, I suspect that's why

Comment: Ok, I'll check that.  Meanwhile, your code runs perfectly in your sandbox (great tool!  I've been looking for something like that.)  So you've given me a working solution.  Thanks!  I'll spend some time tomorrow figuring out what the discrepancy is between the json (which I did output from the real data) and my real data.  If I can't find the answer, I'll go ahead and accept this as the answer to the question posed.

Comment: I use this sandbox tool to test all my code before I put them on SO, easier than to fire up XAMPP. There are other sandbox for PHP like phpfiddle and phptester but out of the three, I like this one the best. Do update me when you work out where the discrepancy lies.

Comment: Problem solved.  As it turns out, I had to do this (not sure why exactly, lifted the code from a friend's app):      `$array = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $array[] = $r;
    }
` to massage the resultset before I got the json which was the starting point of your code.  (Sounds like a different version of the "additional foreach" that you mentioned.)  I had started with a while loop, and got the json by iterating through the resultset, printing line by line, and lifting the result off the page.

Answer (score 2):

`array_push` is the way I'd typically do it. You're code is a bit confusing to read (not very user friendly), but I think you're close - very close...

***EDIT: Check out the below. Should work. Change your `while` to a `foreach` and run it like so:***

```
$rs = [];

foreach(mysql_fetch_array($result) as $key => $row) 
{
    $rs['data'][$key] = array('LineItemNo' => $row['LineItemNo'], 'SolNo' => $row['SolNo'], 'St' => $row['St']);

    $part_info = array('part_no' => $row['PartNo'], 'unit_price' => $row['UnitPrice']);
    $rs['data'][$key]['parts'] = $part_info;
}

print_r($rs);
```

Comment: Thanks Mike.  That's closer, but not all the way.  I only get the parts for the first top-level element.  I'll edit my post to incorporate this.

Comment: Ok, not sure how to do that I guess.  I've edited my answer as well to show what I've tried.  Oh, I had to use `array()` instead of `[]`, for some reason I was getting a syntax error.  Might that have anything to do with the problem?

Comment: Check my edits for some ideas. Note, `$rs[data][parts]` should be `$rs['data']['parts']`

Comment: Curiously, I thought the keys had to be in quotes too, but I tried them without and they worked.

Comment: Prob explains why `[]` weren't working as na array - as it's the same thing. What PHP version you on?

Comment: Mike, I've tried the `foreach` route as well, but I'll have a go again.  It looks like your suggestions (both in the while and the foreach) are making arrays out of `PartNo` and `UnitPrice`.  Is that right?  I want them to be values.  I'm using PHP 5.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I was doing it wrong. Check latest answer. ;)

Comment: Using foreach doesn't solve the problem.  I get the first element right, but the rest is wrong.  There's something wrong with the way that I'm resetting everything when the line item number changes.

Comment: Got it. I needed to write it out and test myself. Hang tight.

Comment: You tried my exact code? Formatting is the same as mine? I tested this with your same array. And got the **exact** result you were looking for in your post.

Comment: Interesting! Weird that it needs to be in a while and that it couldn't just be assigned to a variable then throw in a loop. Glad my days of building using static php are over lol praise frameworks

Comment: I think your code would work too.  I had to loop through the resultset with `mysql_fetch_assoc` and assign the values to an array before I could properly apply SML's code.  I got the starting data by echoing row by row (along with `json_encode`ing each row) inside the `mysql_fetch_array` loop, and it took me a bit (well, I *was* getting tired) to realize that I wasn't working from the same starting point as that.  Thanks for helping out.